# Blender Export: Armature rotation not being applied (cube disappears)

Tags: three.js, blender

I opened a new Blender file, added a bone to the scene, connected it to the cube using ctrl+p (choosing "Bone"), repeated the procedure (adding another cube on the top), switched to Pose Mode, rotated one slightly, exported the scene and saw that the rotation was not applied - the rotated cube is completely missing (see last picture for result).

I was also trying using ctrl+a to apply rotation and location, but it didn't help.

Please note that I'm explicitly looking for non-deforming armature, nothing like weight painting. I want the cube not to change its form in any way.

I'm using Blender 2.78a, Three.js r83 and its Blender exporter, which are, by the time of writing, the latest versions available. For adding the scene, I'm using this code:

```
const loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

loader.load("blender/test.json", (untitled) => {
    this.scene.add(untitled);
});
```

For the export settings, I basically checked every tick in the export settings and chosen "Skeletal animation: Pose".

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]